# Html+css: horizontal side by side 2 DIVs with 3 pictures, 2 of them with transparent background?

Tags: html, css, image, transparent

There are 3 pictures with 2 of them with transparent background (aka layers) and there 3 pictures with 2 of them with transparent background (aka layers) more, totally 6 ones - 2 virtual blocks with 3 pictures each.
That is BasePicL1, NonBasePicL2, NonBasePicL3 is one block and BasePicL4, NonBasePicL5, NonBasePicL6 is other block.
The main purose is to "on/off" "layers" in each "block" by some conditions.
For example, BasePicL1 - is shown, NonBasePicL2 - is hided and NonBasePicL3  - is shown.
Independently the same for other block.
These works by getElementID and set attibute "src" to an appropriate picture (on necessary layer) or to 1 pixel empty (off necessary layer) for got element fine.

But there is necessarity to place these 2 blocks side by side horizontally.

For this I made 2 DIVs, each consists of 3 pictures. Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
         .top-container {
            padding: 20px;
         }
         .img-container-external {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
         } 
        .img-container-internal {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 355px";
            } 
        .overlay-img {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
       <div class=""img-container-external"">
        <img id=""layer1"" class=""overlay-img"" src=""data:image/png;base64,Pic1">
        <img id=""layer2"" class=""overlay-img"" src=""data:image/png;base64,Pic2">
        <img id=""layer3"" class=""overlay-img"" src=""data:image/png;base64,Pic3">
    </div>
    <div class=""img-container-internal"">
        <img id=""layer1"" class=""overlay-img"" src=""data:image/png;base64,Pic4">
        <img id=""layer2"" class=""overlay-img"" src=""data:image/png;base64,Pic5">
        <img id=""layer3"" class=""overlay-img"" src=""data:image/png;base64,Pic6">
    </div> 
    </body>
</html>"
```

This works how I need except 1 thing.
Position of 2nd DIV contaninig Pic4/Pic5/Pic6 is specified statically, for the particular pictures width, in the case as 355 - it is PIc1/Pic2/Pic3 width.

Heigth and width within block1 is the same - Pic1=Pic2=Pic3.
Heigth and width within block2 is the same - Pic4=Pic5=Pic6.
Size of block1 and blocks2 can be different.
And there are many such :blcks: - pixtures kits in our database.

All thse pictures are loaded to some database where is get from to be shown at web page.

Is there way or are there ways to do such by Html+CSS only ?
May be it is possible to make easier - place 2 "blocks" within 1 DIV.
But anyway I need 2 "blocks" be placed as openned book.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the DIVs side by side or how to do so while allowing the DIVs to have different heights? Maybe you're asking how to calculate the width of the first DIV to set the position of the second DIV? Or something else?

Comment: I asked to get the DIVs side by side but contents 3 pictures, 2 of them with transparent background for overlapping.
What I wrote about also.

Your variant looks fine especially of images scaling during window size changing.
But overlapping doesn' t work.
Is it possible to get overlapping images within your suggestion and with fixed left/right  blocks placement ?

Comment: That there must be only two blocks - side by side each other with overlapping of lwithin layer1/layer2/layer3 and layer4/layer5/layer6. Nothing else must be put. If one of block is empty (no images or 1 pixel transparent image only) - it's place is anyway reserved for the block and not occupied by other block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) to position the image blocks side-by-side even when either of the blocks is empty. Grid can also be used to overlay the images inside of the image blocks.

Your code has multiple errors:

1. You have two quotation marks on each side of the attribute values. This can be
   read as an empty value followed by an unrecognized attribute.
2. ID values must be unique (used only once) but you use the same IDs
   in both image blocks.
3. Erroneous quotation mark in CSS: `left: 355px";`

```css
.img-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
}

.img-container-external,
.img-container-internal {
  display: grid;
}

.overlay-img {
  grid-area: 1/1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="img-container-external">
    <img id="layer1" class="overlay-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZDjl.png">
    <img id="layer2" class="overlay-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tk9o.png">
    <img id="layer3" class="overlay-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqiFa.png">
  </div>
  <div class="img-container-internal">
    <img id="layer4" class="overlay-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZDjl.png">
    <img id="layer5" class="overlay-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tk9o.png">
    <img id="layer6" class="overlay-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqiFa.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

The markup can be reduced by using [descendant combinator selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) instead of classes

```css
.img-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
}

.img-container div {
  display: grid;
}

.img-container img {
  grid-area: 1/1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <div>
    <img id="layer1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZDjl.png">
    <img id="layer2" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tk9o.png">
    <img id="layer3" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqiFa.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="layer4" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZDjl.png">
    <img id="layer5" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tk9o.png">
    <img id="layer6" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqiFa.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Regarding double quotations - its is part of a code used in our system and it is interpreted as \"bla-bla\" .
"Erroneous quotation mark" - it is simply slip of tunk.
Anyway, thanks.
I tried you suggestion.
It works fine, but except one very important thing.
Pictures layer2/layer3 and layer5/layer6 are "NonBase layers".  It must be overlayed  on layer1 and layer4 respectively.
But it are displayed near each other
I defined class=""overlay-img-ext"" earlier.
How is to correct this behavior with your suggested way and with overlapping laeyr2/layer3 to layer1 and layer5/layer6 to layer4?

Comment: And one more thing not works as expected.
Layer1/layer2/layer3 must be on the left side, when Layer4/layer5/layer6 on the right size.
If Layer1 is empty image, but layer4 is not, the left side must be an empty, and right side must be filled by layer4 image.
But now in the case layer4 is displayed on the left side.
How is to change it ?

Comment: IF you can please post a code to place constantly left/right, blocks.

Comment: @CpServiceSPb Declare a width. Should the "external" left block always be 355px wide? The three images in my demo are overlapping. One has only grey color, one orange, one green.

Comment: Yes. It is overlapping except Firefox aind IE11 (I don' t have IE10-) 
There are not overlapping at Firefox 115 and IE11.
At Edge is allright.

Regarding left block size, I thought about it and tried so.
But width of blocks can vary from time to time.
For example, now images with 355 pxs are choosen (3 images in 1 block) , other time images with 478 pxs ar choosen.
The question is how is to determine image(s) width ?

Comment: @CpServiceSPb I changed `.img-container` to use grid instead of flex so that the blocks will maintain positions if empty. Works in Firefox 115 on my computer.